# How do I categorize a list in python by value?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of data in python:

```
data=[90,30,13,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,64,69,59,17,22,23,44,25,16,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,59,14,50,55,32,23,24,25,37,28,39,30,33,35,40,34,41,43,94,95,98,99,44,45,47,48,49,53,61,63,69,75,77,60,83]
```

I am trying to sort the data into instances of 10-20, 20-30, 30-40... and have a tally of how many there are in each category. I've tried splitting it into separate lists but I can't make a tally once it's separated

```
    def split_at_values(lst, values):
        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x in values]
        for start, end in zip([0, *indices], [*indices, len(lst)]):
            yield lst[start:end+1]
    values =  {19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 99}
    print(*split_at_values(data, values))
```

Comment: Could you show the code you've tried so far?

Comment: def split_at_values(lst, values):
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x in values]
    for start, end in zip([0, *indices], [*indices, len(lst)]):
        yield lst[start:end+1]
values =  {19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 99}
print(*split_at_values(data, values))

Comment: This just splits at the points and iI'm trying to calcualte how many instances there are if that makes sense?

Comment: @DanT19 you can edit your question. This will allow you to format your code in a readable way.

Comment: what are your buckets? 0-10,11-20,21-30 ... till 91-100?

Comment: yes up to 91-100 and have a tally for each amount of them so in 10-20 there would be 4

Comment: How does `values` relate to the buckets, if at all?

Comment: The values are scores in a test and it's to create a tally with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very nice `Counter` object in the `collections`-package. It is really good (and fast) at counting how much there is of each type.

For your problem:
If we divide all the numbers by `//10` we get the group of each number.  Then we use Counter to count how many is in each group.

```
from collections import Counter
Counter( i//10 for i in data )
```

This gives:

```
Counter({9: 5, 3: 8, 1: 4, 6: 8, 8: 5, 5: 9, 4: 11, 7: 4, 2: 7})
```

which means there are 5 numbers between 90-99, 8 numbers between 30-39 and so on.

But you probably want them sorted and a bit prettier, so we can do this:

```
sorted([f"{k}0-{k}9 : {v}" for k,v in Counter( i//10 for i in data ).items()])
```

This looks like this:

```
sorted([f"{k}0-{k}9 : {v}" for k,v in Counter( i//10 for i in data ).items()])

['10-19 : 4',
 '20-29 : 7',
 '30-39 : 8',
 '40-49 : 11',
 '50-59 : 9',
 '60-69 : 8',
 '70-79 : 4',
 '80-89 : 5',
 '90-99 : 5']
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @ChristianSloper answer, if you also want to classify that data in those groups you can use `groupby` from the itertools module along side `defaultdict` from the collections

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> gdata=defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in groupby(data,key=lambda x:x//10):
    gdata[k].extend(v)


>>> print(gdata)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {9: [90, 94, 95, 98, 99], 3: [30, 32, 37, 39, 30, 33, 35, 34], 1: [13, 17, 16, 14], 6: [67, 64, 69, 67, 61, 63, 69, 60], 8: [85, 87, 85, 87, 83], 5: [50, 51, 59, 50, 51, 59, 50, 55, 53], 4: [45, 44, 45, 40, 41, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49], 7: [72, 72, 75, 77], 2: [22, 23, 25, 23, 24, 25, 28]})
```

and for a more nice printing, we can use pprint

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(gdata)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {1: [13, 17, 16, 14],
             2: [22, 23, 25, 23, 24, 25, 28],
             3: [30, 32, 37, 39, 30, 33, 35, 34],
             4: [45, 44, 45, 40, 41, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49],
             5: [50, 51, 59, 50, 51, 59, 50, 55, 53],
             6: [67, 64, 69, 67, 61, 63, 69, 60],
             7: [72, 72, 75, 77],
             8: [85, 87, 85, 87, 83],
             9: [90, 94, 95, 98, 99]})
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping guys :)